# Populating a table in PostgreSQL and logic formulating

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help in populating a table.

**First** I have an `inventory table` in which holds all of my data and is already populated. The primary key for this table is `terminal_id`

**Second** I have another table, a `down_event table` which holds all of the down event of each machine on the inventory table. It involves the column: `terminal_id`, `event_description`down_date`,`down_time`, and`down_duration_sec` and is already populated.

The one I need to populate is the `availability table` that holds all of the available time of the machines on the `inventory table`. The columns are: `terminal_id`(primary key), `availability_date`(primary key), `availability_time`(primary key), duration_sec.

The catch is that each `terminal_id` needs to have a 1-hour interval in one day meaning 00:00:00 up to 23:59:59 for one terminal_id.

So for example:

```
    terminal_id       availability_time
   _____________     ___________________
    012345678          00:00:00
    012345678          01:00:00
    012345678          02:00:00
    012345678          03:00:00
```

So on and so forth until 23:00:00.
I need help for doing it like that on the availability_table like in the picture below:

[image: availability_table]

Another catch is that the availability_date will come from the `down_event table`. In the `down_event table` each `terminal_id` has different `down_date` that will reflect on the `availability table` that's why in the picture 2019-09-01 keeps being repeated.

I tried populating first the terminal_id so I can try to UPDATE the remaining column but the problem is that I can't because it's a primary key on the `availability table` and won't repeat that's why I'm wondering how did it happen on the result in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following query generates the results you want:

```
select td.terminal_id, td.down_date, (hh * interval '1 hour')::time
from (select distinct terminal_id, down_date
      from down_event_table
     ) td cross join
     generate_series(0, 23) gs(hh);
```

You can then insert these rows into your availability table.

Comment: Thank you so much for these! I'll try to understand the logic behind these!